# The page is refreshing before it complets the jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I've got the following jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $("#Panel1").animate
            ({ width: "1000px", fontSize: "65px" }, 3000);
        });

    });

</script>
```

When i click on the Button some code is going to execute and its going to retrieve a value inside the panel
"so far every thing works fine"

now it's the time for my jQuery code to execute, but when the panel starts to expand the page is refreshing and the jQuery code stop working.

here is my HTML code

```
  <div class="myclass">
  <h1><img id="pic" src="PIC/Capture.PNG" width="100px" hight="100px" /> Company Name</h1>
                <p>This awards are for the hard working staff bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla, still <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="20"></asp:Label> trophy</p>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="wineer" OnClick="Button1_Click" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" Width="127px" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Congratulations"></asp:Label>
    <div class="aa"><asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></asp:Panel></div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="You've won the trophy"></asp:Label>          
    <br />
 </div>
```

How can I make the jQuery code work?

Please advise

Comment: please post code for Button1 markup, i think the page starts a postback on the button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to execute some `javascript` after button click event, i would suggest, use `RegisterStartupScript` in `button_click` event . Reason, this button will always going to `postback` / form submit, and there is some server side code that will be executed for this button click. So it makes sense to call `JS` in button_click via `RegisterStartupScript`.

Wrap the button click ( JS side code) into a function. Like this.

```
function AfterButtonClick(){
  $("#Panel1").animate
            ({ width: "1000px", fontSize: "65px" }, 3000);
}
```

In server side, button click, use following.

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "script", "AfterButtonClick();", true);`

Answer (score 0):

With the limited info.

I would say you need to make sure autopostback is not set to "True" on button1. Also if your using updatepanel, Javescript does not play well with updatepanel.